# Unknown database exception using Hibernate and Jersey

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jersey, dropwizard

I am trying to use Jersey with Hibernate and Dropwizard for the first time and I get this exception when trying to run a Jersey server on the local machine:

> Exception in thread "main" MultiException[com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'mydb'

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver </property>
        <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url"> jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username"> root </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"> </property>
        <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
        <mapping class="annotations.Person"></mapping>       
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Jersey's config.yml contains this part:

```
# Database settings.
database:
    # the name of the JDBC driver, mysql in our case
    driverClass: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    # the username
    user: root
    # the password
    password: 
    # the JDBC URL; the database is called DWGettingStarted
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
    # any properties specific to your JDBC driver:
    properties:
      charSet: UTF-8
      hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

      # the maximum amount of time to wait on an empty pool before throwing an exception
      maxWaitForConnection: 1s

      # the SQL query to run when validating a connection's liveness
      validationQuery: "/* MyApplication Health Check */ SELECT 1"

      # the minimum number of connections to keep open
      minSize: 8

      # the maximum number of connections to keep open
      maxSize: 32

      # whether or not idle connections should be validated
      checkConnectionWhileIdle: false
```

The database itself for now is a file called mydb.mwb and I'm not even sure where it should be located for the connection to succeed. I'm using Xampp for MySql.

What do I need to do for the database file to be recognized? Should I just put it in the Eclipse's project's root folder?

Comment: You are using a myslq database. Does the "mydb" schema exist? E.g. connect to the database on your terminal and do "show databases" to see if it exists. It sounds like you never created that database.

Comment: I didn't.. When asking for the database I simply got the file and was told that the file is the database... what do I need to do with it?

Comment: You need to set up your database correctly. There are heaps of mysql tutorials around. Your issue is not a jersey/dw or hibernate issue but rather a simple database setup problem. Once your database is set up and can be reached, you should be able to connect to it out of the box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, mydb is schema is not available in your mysql database. For this,
You need to import the mydb.mwb in your mysql.

Here is a tutorial: [How to import the mwb file in mysql](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fQH9Z9NVEY0)

After creating mydb schema, hopefully you can run your project successfully.